# How to reply to user reactions that the bot placed?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a bot that looks up stats from an api, if they search for a name that is not in the api it will return some options that match the first three letters of their search. The bot will add reactions for the user to pick one of the listed names,
[bot with players to search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y02b.png)

Now for the part I can't figure out, how do I reply when the user chooses one of the reaction?
I have literally tried 100 different ways and cant get them to work.
Here is my code that I am trying to expand on,

```
message.channel.send(`Could not find player, are you looking for \n` /*+ newArray[0].Name*/);
     for (i = 0; i < player5.length; i++)
     message.channel.send((options[i]) + " " + player5[i].Name)
     
     if(newArray.length >5){
        message.channel.send(`Plaease refine your search, there are ` + (newArray.length - 4) + ` more results \nOr choose reaction to lookup player`).then(function(message) {
   
     for (var i = 0; i < player5.length; i++) {
        message.react(options[i]);
     }
    })
    }else if (newArray.length <5) {
        message.channel.send(`Choose a reaction to lookup player`).then(function(message) {
   
            for (var i = 0; i < player5.length; i++) {
               message.react(options[i])
                }
            
        });   
           
    }
```

Here is one thing that I have tried,

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                return ['1️⃣', '2️⃣'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
                  };
           
            //let filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name == '1️⃣' && user.id == message.author.id || reaction.emoji.name == '2️⃣' && user.id == message.author.id;
            


            message.awaitReactions(filter, { max: i+1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(collected => {
                    const reaction = collected.first();
            
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣' && reaction.count > 1) {
                        message.reply('you picked ' + player5[0].Name );
                    } else if (reaction.emoji.name === '2️⃣' && reaction.count > 1){
                        message.reply('you picked ' + player5[1].Name);
                    }
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                    message.reply('you reacted with neither a thumbs up, nor a thumbs down.');
                });
```

Comment: I figured it out

Comment: you can answer your own questions and that'd help people who stumble upon your questions from Google

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work,

```
if (reaction.emoji.name === '1️⃣' && reaction.count > 1) {
             let player1 = statsValue.filter(function (entry) {
                 return entry.PlayerName === player5[0].Name;
             }) // remainder of code
```